# Dynamic forms by user in php?

Tags: php, mysql

Here in my PHP application, I need to allow users to create a registration forms customized for themselves. They will be having the privilege of choosing the number fields, their names as well as there type. The table for the data also will be created dynamically in MySQL.
Now I want to know if there is any library out there which could lessen my work or will I have to do it the harder way? 
Thanks.

Comment: You do not need to create dynamic tables to have custom registration forms. There are a million and one "survey creator" scripts and services which are exactly what you're describing, you're reinventing the wheel. Just send your client to http://wufoo.com/

Comment: sorry i didn't add the complete information. Mine is an offline application to be shown in the college. So the most of the coding done by me myself, the better..

Comment: Moreover, "reinventing the wheel" that you are referring to is an effective and widely used process to develop and acquire the concepts that go behind "making a wheel".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo can try `CROOGO` dynamics forms a CakePHP CMS.

It is having a very good plugin where admin can customize it's form with validation facility and also relate two fields if required (eg: Password and confirm password should be same.

For core php. You to structure your db by using SAAS model.

refrence:`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180803/what-kind-of-database-is-used-in-dynamic-form-builder`

Comment: I'm gonna have a look at these. Thanks :)